# Set the dataGridColumn's ItemRenderer dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, itemrenderer

I have this DataGrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myDataGrid">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="colA" headerText="Column A:" width="40"
            headerRenderer="path.customComponents.VerticalHeader"
            itemRenderer="path.customComponents.CustomDataGridItemRenderer" />
    </mx:Columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Only I don't know in advance how many columns there will be. So I tried building the columns with a function in ActionScript:

```
private var _columns:Array;

[Bindable]
public function set columns(value:Array):void
{
    var c:Array = [];
    for each(var object:Object in value)
    {
        var column:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
        column.headerText=object.name;
        column.width=40;

        // Setting the Renderers like this doesn't work!
        column.headerRenderer = 
                path.customComponents.VerticalHeader;
        column.itemRenderer = 
                path.customComponents.CustomDataGridItemRenderer;

        c.push(c);
    }
    myDataGrid.columns = c;
}
public function get columns():Array
{
    return _columns;
}
```

But for some reason, the renders cannot be set like this. (column.itemRenderer = com.ItemRenderer).

What is the proper way to set these renders dynamically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`itemRenderer` and `headerRenderer` expects an `mx.core.IFactory` as its value. In mxml, the string value that you pass is automatically converted into `mx.core.ClassFactory`. In ActionScript, you have to do it yourself.

```
column.itemRenderer 
            = new ClassFactory(path.customComponents.CustomDataGridItemRenderer);
```